# How to go from a values_list to a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I have a django queryset that returns a list of values:

```
[(client pk, timestamp, value, task pk), (client pk, timestamp, value, task pk),....,].
```

I am trying to get it to return a dictionary of this format:

```
{client pk:[[timestamp, value],[timestamp, value],...,], client pk:[list of lists],...,}
```

The values_list may have multiple records for each client pk.  I have been able to get dictionaries of lists for client or task pk using:

```
def dict_from_vl(vls_list):
    keys=[values_list[x][3] for x in range(0,len(values_list),1)]
    values = [[values_list[x][1], values_list[x][2]] for x in range(0,len(values_list),1)]
    target_dict=dict(zip(keys,values))
    return target_dict
```

However using this method, values for the same key write over previous values as it iterates through the values_list, rather than append them to a list.  So this works great for getting the most recent if the values list is sorted oldest records to newest, but not for the purpose of creating a list of lists for the dict value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `target_dict=dict(zip(keys,values))`, do

```
target_dict = defaultdict(list)
for i, key in enumerate(keys):
    target_dict[k].append(values[i])
```

(`defaultdict` is available in the standard module `collections`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for x in vls_list:
   d[x].append(list(x[1:]))
```

Although I'm not sure if I got the question right.

Answer (score 1):

I know in Python you're supposed to cram everything into a single line, but you could do it the old fashioned way...

```
def dict_from_vl(vls_list):
    target_dict = {}
    for v in vls_list:
        if v[0] not in target_dict:
            target_dict[v[0]] = []
        target_dict[v[0]].append([v[1], v[2]])
    return target_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

For better speed, I suggest you don't create the keys and values lists separately but simply use only one loop:

```
tgt_dict = defaultdict(list)
for row in vas_list:
    tgt_dict[row[0]].append([row[1], row[2]])
```

Comment: So if the values_list is passed to this method as vls_list, how does this look as a def statement.  I guess I am not seeing how the row[0] works to get the first value for each list in the list of lists.

Comment: You have a list of tuples 'vls_list' (sorry that was a typo for 'vas_list'), when you do 'for row in vls_list:', it actually iterates vls_list tuple by tuple, so row[0] will be 'client pk'. If I understood it correctly, you want to use 'client pk' as the key. However, you can use any item in the tuple as the key anyway by using the proper index.